# How can you intialize Arrays of Arrays of fixed size?

Tags: contract-development, blockchain, arrays

Hi guy's so for exemple we have the following struct :

```
struct Foo {
uint256[10][10][2] a;
}
mapping (uint256 => Foo) private fooByID;
function create(_ID) public {
Foo foo = Foo(???)
}
```

I know how to do it when it's a simple array with the following syntax
`uint256[](size)`
but when it's nested array I can't seem to find a way to do it.
Any help would be welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

this should work:

```
  Foo memory foo;
  foo.a[0][0][0] = 1;
```